# Postion wont be editable by javascript if it is inherited

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the position of my div called `player` is styled to `position:absolute;` I can move its position with JavaScript but if it's inherited or fixed so its position is fixed to the parent div I cannot control it with JavaScript anymore.

html of the divs that.

```
<div id="game">
    <div id="player"></div>
    <div id="scores"><h1 id="playersScore"> 0</h1><h1 id="pcScore"> 0</h1></div>
</div>
```

javascript that updates the top position of the div

```
function readMouseMove(e){
    if(e.clientY < 500){
        var player = document.getElementById('player');
        player.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
    }

document.onmousemove = readMouseMove;
```

the css of the player is

```
#player{
    border:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    top:50px;
    background-color:#00FF00;
    width:8px;
    height:50px;
}
```

the parent div css is

```
#game{
    margin:150px auto;
    border:3px solid black;
    background-color:black;
    width:1000px;
    height:500px;
}
```

Now this player div is been controlled by the javascript but if I change the position to `positon:inherit` I cannnot control the div with javascript anymore. I need to have the player divs positon to relate to its parent div.

Comment: you have to set the parent's position to `relative`, then it will become the containing block context for the child.

Comment: well sir this fixed my problem! i feel so stupid >_<!

Comment: For reference, `fixed` isn't fixed relative to the parent. It's relative to the viewport.

Comment: Guys, maybe you should write the answer into answer box, and not in the comments?

Comment: ^ this! i would thumb his set his Answer as the Helping one if he did @KingKing

Comment: never mind, this is a common (and basic) problem in CSS. Commenting is enough, I'm a bit lazy to find the duplicated questions about this right on SO.